# Is there a limit to how many nukes I can have?

Tags: civilization-6

I started producing nukes in a few different cities, and when making them, they simply state something like they add one more nuke to my reserves. Is there a limit to how many nukes I can have, or can I just keep stockpiling them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't seen any indication that there is a limit, but the maintenance costs are pretty steep at 14-16 gold per turn. So your stockpile is certainly limited by your wallet.

Nukes are not bound to individual submarines or silos, you just have a central stockpile and can fire from any of those. They don't have a capacity for nukes or something like that.

Comment: Well, I have like +300 gold per turn, so I should be able to stockpile quite a few. And I don't have to pay maintenance if I use them.

Answer (score -3):

Nukes *do* have a limit, well no really you can have as much nukes as you want *but*, you need uranium. Even though you might have lots of uranium *eventually* the world well run out.

Comment: Uranium is not consumed when the nukes are made